# How can Kotlin extension classes replace the decorator design pattern?

Tags: kotlin, design-patterns, decorator

Kotlin's documentation makes this statement:

> Kotlin provides an ability to extend a class with new functionality
> without having to inherit from the class or use design patterns such
> as Decorator.

[Kotlin Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html)

I am having trouble understanding how extension functions can *completely* replace the decorator design pattern.

To borrow an example from TutorialPoint how would you turn the below example into code that only used extension functions? Can you do this without sacrificing the ability to call `draw()` on both concrete shape objects and decorated shape objects?

```
interface Shape {
 fun draw();
}

class Rectangle: Shape {
 override fun draw() {
  println("Shape: Rectangle")
 }
}

class Circle: Shape {
 override fun draw() {
  System.out.println("Shape: Circle");
 }
}

abstract class ShapeDecorator(protected val decoratedShape: Shape): Shape {

 override fun draw(){
  decoratedShape.draw();
 }
}

class RedShapeDecorator(decoratedShape:Shape): ShapeDecorator(decoratedShape) {

 override fun draw() {
  decoratedShape.draw();
  setRedBorder(decoratedShape);
 }

 private fun setRedBorder(decoratedShape:Shape){
  System.out.println("Border Color: Red");
 }
}

fun main(){

 val circle: Shape = Circle();

 val redCircle: Shape  = RedShapeDecorator(Circle());

 val redRectangle: Shape = RedShapeDecorator(Rectangle());
  
 
 System.out.println("Circle with normal border");
 circle.draw();

 System.out.println("\nCircle of red border");
 redCircle.draw();

 System.out.println("\nRectangle of red border");
 redRectangle.draw();
}
```

[TutorialPoint Example in Java](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/decorator_pattern.htm)

Comment: Extensions are not a replacement for every possible use of the decorator pattern. The statement you quoted is only saying it *can* avoid the need for the decorator pattern if you are only using the pattern to add functions to a class without subclassing it.

Comment: OK so then extensions cannot replace the Decorator design pattern if the concrete decorator adds extra code to a method inside the concrete decorated class? In the example draw() in RedShapeDecorator prints "Border Color: Red" as well as the shape name. Is this not re-writable with extensions?

Comment: This is example is not analogous to what extension functions can do, because they cannot affect inheritance or override functions.

Comment: This statement from the Kotlin docs says that extensions are just another way of extending an existing class. Extensions are much different than decorator pattern or subtyping, because the user needs to use them intentionally, while subtyping/decorator is transparent to the user. This is why extensions can't really replace other patterns. They are just another handy tool, more lightweight than decorator, but limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a question of design reasoning or philosophy. First decorator Pattern is better known as Wrapper Classes. The wrapper/decorator does this so that you conceal details from the user of feature (which is being wrapped)/wrappee, add or make some change to a feature of the wrappee. And then it adds a layer of abstraction. With this abstraction it allows easy change of wrappee class in future if needed.
In your example I do not see the purpose of ShapeDecorator/ShapeWrapper - What is it really wrapping and for what purpose? - Interface itself is a contract.

In Kotlin by default all classes & functions are final and closed. This was done to enforce some of the effective Java Principles (Joshua Bloch). Thus again enforcing you to not inherit the class but use Wrapper Pattern or Extension.

So now for the difference between Extension and Wrapper. If u just need to extend to add some functionality that the original creator of the base class missed out and you can not make changes in the base class or feel it not the right place to do that then u are going for Extension Function. It is not concealing anything, not adding any abstraction layer (one or more).
But if it is for the purpose of the abstraction, decoration then u go for decorator.
Extension functions do not replace decorator pattern. It can be avoided if not needed.

Also Extension fun by statically dispatched - In very very simple words they become static methods in java decompilation (Thus u see again that abstraction is missing).

This is a quickly written ans.